# How to edit .bash_profile or .profile file. and Append the following text into it so these two commands will be executed every time the user login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-agent, vps

In the following article https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/setup-passwordless-ssh-login it says to edit `.bash_profile` or `.profile`.

But I haven’t understood this line:

> Then edit .bash_profile or .profile file. Append the following text into it so these two commands will be executed every time the user login.

```
/usr/bin/keychain $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
source $HOME/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-sh
```

My `/root/.profile` contains:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

if [ “$BASH” ]; then
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
. ~/.bashrc
fi
fi

mesg n 2> /dev/null || true
```

So where to add the code can you please give me the modified file ??

Thanks

Comment: The web site says "Append the following text". This means, it should go to the end.

Comment: Depending on your configuration, I would also ensure that `.profile` is the correct script to be modified. Perhaps `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` is more appropriate.